# How to limit the number of processes in a local MRJob task

Tags: python, hadoop, mrjob

I am running a MapReduce job on an 8-core machine using MRJob. I wrote it using the Python API, and I run it as

```
$ python main.py -r local files/input*
```

There are ~750 input files in that folder, and when I run it that way, I believe mrjob launches as many mapper processes as there are input files. Even thought  the machine has 8-cores, I see the load average as

```
load average: 551.26, 553.29, 556.82
```

Isn't there a way to limit the number of mappers, so that it only launches 8 (or 16) of them at a time? I couldn't find a config option for this, which suggests I'm doing something wrong somewhere?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is the rough outline of my MRjob task.

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep

class MyMR(MRJob):

    def mapper_xml_init(self):
        self.abuf = ""

    def mapper_xml(self, _, line):

        self.abuf += line.strip()

        # ... work with self.abuf

        if acondition:
            self.abuf = ""


    def reducer_mean(self, _, values):
        # process some stuff

    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep(mapper_init=self.mapper_xml_init, 
                   mapper=self.mapper_xml),  

            MRStep(reducer=self.reducer_mean),
        ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMR.run()
```

Comment: Can you give me some more details on how you access Hadoop in your main.py?

Comment: @StefanPapp, thanks for asking for more info! I added the rough outline of the job. I'm running this for all files in a folder. Any ideas why I get 700 processes?